# ¿Cómo solucionar el error "Primitivo JSON no válido"?

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy enviando 4 parámetros a un JsonResult desde Ajax con Json:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GenerarCertificadosSeleccionados", "Firmar")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {
                array_interesados: JSON.stringify(array_interesados),
                    id_charla: id_charla,
                    titulo_charla: titulo_charla,
                    fecha_charla: fecha_charla 
                },
            dataType: "json",
```

Y al momento de ejecutar me aparece el error "Primitivo JSON no válido", pensé que se solucionaría con el JSON.strinfy(), pero no.

Aquí tengo mi JsonResult:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GenerarCertificadosSeleccionados(List<ClsInteresado> array_interesados, string id_charla, string titulo_charla, string fecha_charla)
    {
        List<ClsInteresadoArchivo> temporal = new List<ClsInteresadoArchivo>();

        GenerarPdfs(array_interesados, id_charla, titulo_charla, fecha_charla);

        string[] archivos;

        try
        {
            archivos = ObtenerNombreArchivos();

            foreach (var item in array_interesados)
            {
                ClsInteresadoArchivo i = new ClsInteresadoArchivo();
                i.dni_Inter = item.dni_Inter;
                i.nombres_Inter = item.nombres_Inter;
                i.apePat_Inter = item.apePat_Inter;
                i.apeMat_Inter = item.apePat_Inter;

                temporal.Add(i);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < archivos.Count(); i++)
            {
                temporal[i].nombreArchivo_Inter = archivos[i];
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json("error");
        }

        return Json(temporal);
    }
```

Como pueden ver, estoy enviando una lista y 3 datos únicos. Quisiera saber qué estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 1):

Tu `JSON` esta mal generado

Este es un JSON normal

```
var array_interesados= {
                   id_charla: id_charla,
                    titulo_charla: titulo_charla,
                    fecha_charla: fecha_charla 
};
```

Este es un `JSON` como el que tu necesitas, que contiene un `array` Notese el `[]`

```
var array_interesados= [
                       { id_charla: id_charla,
                        titulo_charla: titulo_charla,
                        fecha_charla: fecha_charla},
                        { id_charla: id_charla2,
                        titulo_charla: titulo_charla2,
                        fecha_charla: fecha_charla2 },
                       ];
```

Para generar tu JSON con arrays dinamicamente podrias usar lo siguiente:

```
for(var i in tusDatos) {    


    array_interesados.push({ 
        "id_charla" : tusDatos[i].id_charla,
        "titulo_charla"  : tusDatos[i].titulo_charla,
        "fecha_charla"       : itusDatos[i].fecha_charla
    });
}
```

Y mandas tu objeto en data de esta manera

```
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("GenerarCertificadosSeleccionados", "Firmar")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(array_interesados),
        dataType: "json",
```